# What is the following property of inequality called?

Tags: inequality

I found the following on Wikipedia, [on the page for Inequalities](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Elementary_algebra&oldid=633621020#Properties_of_inequality):

> If $a<b$ and $c<d$ then $a+c < b+d$.

It references [Intermediate Algebra](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=b3vqad8tbiAC&lpg=PA96&ots=FF2OYYGNCV&dq=algebra%20inequality%20properties&pg=PA96#v=onepage&q=algebra%20inequality%20properties&f=false), but I don't see this specific property there.

Is there a name for this particular property? Is there a proof for this property from the other properties?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300920/adding-equations-in-triangle-inequality-proof/300977#300977

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This holds in any ordered field (or more generally, partially ordered group); the only property we need to take advantage of is translation invariance and transitivity. That is, the properties that
$$a<b\Leftrightarrow a+c<b+c$$
$$a<b \text{ and } b<c\Rightarrow a<c$$

Starting with
$$a<b$$
we can, using translation invariance, add a constant to both sides:
$$a+c<b+c$$
We can, using translation invariance, we can also establish, from $c<d$ translated by $b$ get that
$$b+c<b+d$$
and using transitivity gives
$$a+c<b+d$$

Comment: Very elegant, thank you!

Comment: Why does it have to be a field?  Wouldn't you only need an ordered group since there is only one operation?

Comment: @D_R That's a good point and I edited to include it; it even holds in any *partially* ordered group, I suppose - the only difference in the proof of that would be that left-addition and right-addition might not be the same, so you need an additional property (i.e. $a<b\Leftrightarrow c+a<c+b$).

Comment: Partial ordering has only less than or equal to comparisons?

Comment: @D_R Partial ordering has that $a\leq b$ and $b\leq a$ could *both* be false - that is, $a$ and $b$ could be incomparable (whereas total ordering asserts that at least one of those holds). The difference between $\leq$ and $<$ is purely one of notation, since you can easily define one given the other.

Comment: I never remember these semantics

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the name.

But proof: yes. If $p$ and $q$ are positive numbers, then $p + q$ is a positive number; this follows from a commonly used postulate of the real number system. We can take $a < b$ to mean $b - a$ is positive.

Now let $p = b - a$ and $q = d - c$. Both are positive hence $p + q = (b + d) - (a + c)$ is as well. Therefore

$$a < b \ \text{ and } \ c < d \ \ \Longrightarrow \ \ a + c < b + d$$